# Web app not handling URL response correctly

Tags: facebook, web-applications, uiwebview, ios8

I have an iOS web-app where users can login with Google or Facebook. When the native Google or Facebook apps sends back the users to my app after login, I get this error message:

```
didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"
UserInfo=0x16887f2c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://website.com/, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://website.com/}
```

I believe it's due to the UIWebView not handling some URLs properly, I cannot find why the ones Google or Facebook send back trigger this error.

Any help appreciated.